# How to add within cluster variance to cluster plot using fviz_cluster?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, variance

I have multiple cluster plots and I want to add a label that shows the within-cluster variance of each cluster in the plot. I tried using geom_label to add the text but that doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried looking in the fviz_cluster documentation but I couldn't seem to find anything that would help with what I wanted.
Here is my code:

```
k2 <- kmeans(protein.scaled, centers = 2,
                     iter.max = 1, nstart =  25)
k3 <- kmeans(protein.scaled, centers = 3,
                     iter.max = 1, nstart = 25)
k4 <- kmeans(protein.scaled, centers = 4,
                     iter.max = 1, nstart = 25)
k5 <- kmeans(protein.scaled, centers = 5,
                     iter.max = 1, nstart = 25)
k6 <- kmeans(protein.scaled, centers = 6,
                     iter.max = 1, nstart = 25)

k1_4 <- KMeans(protein.scaled, centers=2, 
                  iter.max=100, num.seeds = 1)
p2 <- fviz_cluster(k2, geom = "point", data = protein.scaled,
                   xlab = "Cereals", ylab = "RedMeats", 
                   stand = FALSE) + ggtitle("k = 2") + 
  geom_label(aes(label = k2$withinss/(nrow(protein.scaled)-2)),
             position = "identity") 


p2
p3 <- fviz_cluster(k3, geom = "point",  data = protein.scaled,
                   xlab = "Cereals", ylab = "RedMeats") + ggtitle("k = 3")
p4 <- fviz_cluster(k4, geom = "point",  data = protein.scaled,
                   xlab = "Cereals", ylab = "RedMeats") + 
        ggtitle("k = 4")
p5 <- fviz_cluster(k5, geom = "point",  data = protein.scaled,
                   xlab = "Cereals", ylab = "RedMeats") + ggtitle("k = 5")
p6 <- fviz_cluster(k6, geom = "point",  data = protein.scaled,
                   xlab = "Cereals", ylab = "RedMeats") + ggtitle("k = 6")

pk4 <- fviz_cluster(k1_4, geom = "point", data = protein.scaled,
                    xlab = "Cereals", ylab = "RedMeats") +
  ggtitle("k=6 run 100 times")
```

Thanks for any help!